# « Daulphins, fleurs de lis, estoille de cresme fricte [...] » : formes de « gâteaux » ?

Tags: prépositions, terminologie, alimentation, figure-de-style, moyen-français

Au *Dictionnaire du Moyen Français* on trouve à l'entrée [*fleur-de-lys*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/fleur-de-lis?idf=dmfXhgYrmXart.revusYflXgb;str=0) (substantif féminin) un sens en *pâtisserie* qu'au *Godefroy* (*Complément*, à [*fleur de lis*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/complement-godefroy/fleur%20de%20lis)) on dit être une « sorte de gâteau sucré, découpé en la manière d'une fleur de lis », et des références à trois exemples du 15<sup>e</sup> siècle où le terme *dauphin/daulphin* apparaît toujours concurremment :

> *DAULPHINS*, fleurs de lis, estoille de cresme fricte fort sucre et moyeulx d'eufz. ([lien](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k62367s/f154.item.r=fleur%20de%20lis))
>
> Daulphins, Fleurs de lys, Estoille de cresme tous sucre.
>   ([lien](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k62367s/f126.item.r=Fleur%20de%20lys))
>  [ [*Le viandier*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viandier), de [Guillaume Tirel dit
>   Taillevent](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_Tirel), publ. par le baron Pichon et Georges Vicaire ]
>
> ---
>
> Fay qu il y ait grues, panneaux
>  Herons et petis sigongneaux,
>   Levraulx, perdris, cailles, lappins,
>  Faisandeaux (ce sont bons
>   loppins),
>  Venaison, rostie et empaste ;
>  Despeche toy tost et
>   te haste :
>  Cella souffira pour ce jour :
>  Puis après ilz
>   auront les four
>  **Dauphins et fleurdelis de cresme,**
>  Gasteaux
>   et bons ratons de mesme ;
>  Je vueil qu'ilz soient tresbien
>   traictez.
>  Despechez vous et vous hastez !
>  Le plus tost que
>   on peult, que on le face.
>
> [ [*Le mistère du viel testament*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5054m/f533.item) ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mist%C3%A9re_du_Viel_Testament)), T. 4, v. 36112/**36120**, publ. baron de Rothschild ]

---

- La formule avec préposition [*de*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/de) et la [*crème*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cr%C3%A8me) réfère-t-elle à la *composition* du dessert dans les exemples, ou est-ce plutôt l'ellipse de l'apport de la garniture au tout (*avec de la crème en garniture..., un [glaçage](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870566)*), ou autre chose ; est-ce que c'est figé/ça participe de la sémantique du [*gâteau*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/g%C3%A2teau), généralement une « préparation de pâte sucrée cuite au four » (TLFi) ?
- Est-il généralement courant au lexique dans le domaine de voir des noms référant à l'emblème ou aux symboles actuels ([de la France](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embl%C3%A8mes_de_la_France) plus particulièrement), désigner des *pâtisseries* par métonymie, comme ce semble être le cas ici avec d'anciens [emblèmes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dauphin_(titre)#/media/File:Coat_of_Arms_of_the_Dauphin_of_France.svg) ?
- Existe-t-il un terme plus précis en pâtisserie aujourd'hui qui désignerait ces *dauphins, fleurs de lis* et *étoiles* (une... *sorte de gâteau*) ?

Comment: L'expression complète avec le mot **dauphin** semble être **four dauphin**, qui désigne, par métonymie, une pâtisserie. Il paraît possible que cette pâtisserie soit aussi connue sous le nom de Fleur de Lys, bien que le **et** dans la citation pourrait laisser penser que non. Quant à **étoiles**, c'est probablement une description de la forme dessinée sur l a pâtisserie, ou bien de la forme même de la pâtisserie  pour évoquer la Fleur de Lys

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington Merci ! J'avais remarqué l'absence de ponct. après _four_ mais je n'avais pas pensé le lire ainsi ; de plus je ne sais pas exactement si ce qui suit (_Gasteaux et bons ratons de mesme_) appuyait ou se distinguait de ce qui précède. Dans les ex. au _viandier_, la présentation lexicographique me laisse perplexe, avec les dauphins en majuscule et en italiques au premier exemple, et le terme dans une liste, me laissant croire de prime abord que le premier valait pour une catégorie. Enfin un français plus ancien où l'usage des prépos. peut différer me laisse ds. le doute...

Answer (score 3):

- ... *de crème* semble être une description de la garniture plutôt que de la composition du gâteau. En effet il est plus courant d'utiliser la crème en garniture que dans la pâte du gâteau. Aujourd'hui, on dirait *à la crème*.
- En regardant une [liste de pâtisseries](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_de_p%C3%A2tisseries), il semble être assez rare de nos jours d'utiliser des noms d'emblèmes. Le seul dans cette liste qui paraît entrer dans ce schéma est le Concorde mais c'est un peu une nouveauté. On a plus souvent l'habitude d'employer des noms fantaisistes.
- Ces noms sont probablement déjà *précis*, au sens où ils devaient sûrement être aussi compréhensibles pour un lecteur de l'époque que le seraient des termes comme "profiteroles" aujourd'hui. Mais il n'existe probablement pas d'équivalent moderne, les techniques de pâtisserie ayant beaucoup changé entre-temps. Par exemple, les bases comme le biscuit génois, la pâte à choux, ou encore la pâte feuilletée dans sa forme moderne n'étaient pas encore inventées.